# Is 90 minutes enough time to get through customs at Buenos Aires Airport on a transit flight?

Tags: transit, short-connections, aep

We are looking to book a flight from Santiago, Chile to El Calafate, Argentina, but the layover in Buenos Aires is only 90 minutes. Is that enough time to get through customs?

Comment: Immigration would probably be the one I'd worry more about!

Comment: Which airport in Buenos Aires? What time of day?

Comment: @pnuts The question is tagged with AEP

Comment: @pnuts er, why did you ask which airport then?

Comment: @pnuts ok, my mistake. I just imagined you wrote it in bold.

Answer (score 3):

From [10 years ago](https://forum.virtualtourist.com/Buenos_Aires-1541981-6-3302724/AEP-flight-connection-time-between-Aerolineas-and-LAN.html?showPost=608419) *AEP is a great airport - modern and easy to get through. Enjoy your time there.* but a decade is not *very* long in the life of most airports. Post was asking about a 1hr 45m layover (but with luggage collection). Conclusions were that that was enough time despite the arrival flight in that case being by an airline quite well known for tardiness (Aerolineas Argentinas). LAN from Chile may be more reliable `*`.

Recently (CaraCPT at [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294266-i977-k9123139-Clearing_customs_in_Argentina-Argentina.html) at 01 January 2016, 23:08):

> I arrived at AEP at 22:20 from South Africa via Brazil was through customs and in my hotel just after 23:00 ... I think you should have enough time. Just my opinion.

`*` OOps. The 90m connection I was thinking of is not LAN/AA as I had recalled but AA/AA (admittedly showing as 1hr 40m). However, that should mean that as a through flight passenger is protected against delay in arrival at AEP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Ezeiza airport was that it was pretty fast so we literally never noticed any delay. Make sure you come and go from the same airport!

Both on our way in and out there were no long lines or delays, first time in the evening, second time early morning.

However you should check whether you will need to pay the reciprocity fee. That's substantial amount of money and time lost, especially if you won't take measures in advance. Might also make you reconsider laying over at Buenos Aires (only relevant if you're bound for some 3rd country). Luckily we didn't need to pay it, as do EU citizens, but not US, who have to pony up.

Also consider that if you're arriving by long-range flight, it might be delayed. Should probably not be a problem when flying from Chile.

Comment: I had the same experience on Wednesday at EZE. Plane seat to taxi seat in twenty minutes.

Comment: @alamar Not all EU citizens pay the reciprocity fee. British citizens don't.

Comment: @pnuts Yes sorry, I got that meaning after I wrote my comment. I edited it accordingly to withdraw the address to you.